# Heroku h10 error uninitialized constant CarrierWave (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, carrierwave

I'm getting an h10 error when I try to deploy a rails app with git on heroku.
The log shows that it exits at the point where it shows the message:

```
2013-03-14T12:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:3:in `<top     (required)>': uninitialized constant CarrierWave (NameError)
2013-03-14T12:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:439:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2013-03-14T12:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `each'
2013-03-14T12:00:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:438:in `block in eager_load!'
```

Can someone please help me with this? I have tried many things and I can't seem to find a solution.. I have the carrierwave gem in my Gemfile and an image_uploader.rb just like explained on railscasts

Answer (score 0):

Have you included gem 'carrierwave' in your Gemfile?